# How to read json object's value keyed by "#key"?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is part of lastfm response. How can I get image url in JavaScript?

```
"image":[
   {"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34\/52430157.jpg","size":"small"},     
   {"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64\/52430157.jpg","size":"medium"},  
   {"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/52430157.jpg","size":"large"}
]
```

Also a have a problem with getting "rank" value

```
{"artist":[{
  "playcount":"111",
  "mbid":"0944e98f-0b9f-4574-babc-7badf4cd0f74",
  "streamable":"1",
  "@attr":{"rank":"1"}
}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `image[0]["#text"]`, for example, to get the first url stored in #text.

Comment: Using that notation, it's pretty easy to go through a loop and grab all the values for the first example. The second example is pretty straightforward with bracket notation as well.